# Dialog display in Windows Mobile6.0

Tags: windows-mobile

This is the what linking error's i got when i created one dialog box for windows mobile 6.0

1>dynamenu.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "long **cdecl DisplayDlg(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?DisplayDlg@@YAJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z) referenced in function "long **cdecl WndProc(struct HWND** *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WndProc@@YAJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)

1>Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)\Debug/Dynamenu.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

What would be the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the name "DisplayDlg".  In Win32 you will use the DialogBox() function.